# Casting from unknown pointer to class; how to check validity?

Tags: c++, windows, casting

I am using the `LPARAM` (essentially a `long`, unless we're on a 64-bit system in which case it is a `long long`) member of an `LVITEM` (called `lParam`) to store a pointer to the object that coincides with that entry in the `ListView`.

When I want to edit that item, I want to cast that `LPARAM` to a `MyClass*`, which works fine so long as the `lParam` is correctly set to be equal to a `MyClass*` in the first place, but I'd like to do some kind of checking to *make sure* it is, in fact, a `MyClass` that this number is pointing to.

Currently I have this:

```
LVITEM lv;
// lv is filled in by LVM_GETITEM
classPtr = static_cast<MyClass*>((void*)lv.lParam);
if ( !classPtr )
    return false;
```

Now, I'm not exactly clear: does `static_cast` return `NULL` if the argument is not a valid pointer? I assume not, since that's what `dynamic_cast` is for, but I'm not entirely certain. And, if I am correct in this assumption, is there any way to check that `classPtr` is valid before I attempt to access its members and cause a crash...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't check it at all in pure standard C++. You can only do a probabilistic check using the Windows API. So, in practice you can only guarantee it, by making your code correct.

If you could check it you would still not know that it was *the* correct `MyClass` instance.

So, the only good way is to make your code guaranteed correct. That's easier when you limit access to things. C++ has many features to help you limit access, e.g. `const`; use them.

Cheers &  hth.,

Comment: that's not always possible, sometimes it's a component based design. you want to check if the component is Type A do Athings with it and if it's type B do BThings!

Comment: @Gajet: That's what `virtual` methods are for. The user of components shouldn't have to know if an object is of type A or type B. As long as both types implement the required `virtual` methods, then component users can just call them with no regards to their actual type and they'll do their job.

Comment: @Alf: I agree with this, I was just wondering if there was a way to double-check. I mean, I am _trying_ to do this, but double-checking would make me feel safer. Ah, well, I'll just have to be extra careful.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: There really isn't anything you can do against determined idiots or evil programmers. The best you can do is to provide an interface that's easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly.

Comment: @insilico: there are some rare cases which you need to use dynamic_cast, at least it's there for some reason! and there are some use cases in my mind right now, but describing them won't fit here. just one : i have list of layers in my game, they can either be object layers or tile layers, to retrieve a tile properties I have to first check if the current layer is a tile layer or not (and that's not something you can do with virutal funcitons).

Answer (score 5):

`static_cast<>` performs no runtime checking of types, so what you have won't work, at least not the way you think it does. All `static_cast<>` does is pointer arithmetic based on information known at compile time.

`dynamic_cast<>` *might* work, but it requires that the class has at least one virtual function (for RTTI) and it'll surely fail badly if `LPARAM` isn't even a pointer to something that's a class type.

There is no general way to determine, given an arbitrary pointer or integral value like an `LPARAM`, that it actually points to an instance of `MyClass`.

What I would do in your specific situation is to wrap the list view in its own class and expose methods that works with `MyClass` only. Possibly like this:

```
class MyListView
{
public:
    MyListView() { /* create the list view HWND */ }
    ~MyListView() { /* destroy the list view HWND */ }

    void Add(MyClass* listItem) // Only way to add items to list view
    {
        // Add to list view
    }

    MyClass* Get() const
    {
        LVITEM lv;
        // lv is filled in by LVM_GETITEM

        // Assume that this will work, since the only way to add
        // list view items is through Add(), and Add() only accepts
        // an instance of MyClass. Therefore the list view will only
        // have pointers to instances of MyClass.
        return static_cast<MyClass*>((void*)lv.lParam);
    }

    // ...

private:
    // Set to private so users can't modify
    // the list view without our consent.
    HWND listView;
};
```

The advantage of this method is that now you have complete control over the list view control and its interface, and thus this will always work (bugs and evil/incompetent programmers  notwithstanding). You can even make it a template so that it works with classes other than `MyClass`.

Comment: Ah, that is an excellent idea, except I'm not sure that making `listView` `private` will do exactly what we want here, because while they won't be able to access it through `MyClass`, if they got it some other way (I'm not familiar enough with the Windows API to be certain, but I'm reasonably sure you can get the `HWND` of the control through it without going through `MyClass`). This helps, and is also a convenient way to handle things, but I'm not sure it's ultimately a hard-lock on the list-view.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: Note that I said "bugs and evil/incompetent programmers notwithstanding". :-) Of course they'll always find another way to grab the `HWND`. If they really, really want to do modify the `HWND`, they'll get it. But encapsulating the `HWND` in some way is much, much better than letting the `HWND` exist "in plain view". Aim to provide an interface that's easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

If the `LPARAM` is not a pointer of type `MyClass` but rather an arbitrary bit pattern, both `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` will show undefined behaviour. `dynamic_cast` returns `NULL` if a pointer to a *valid  object* is cast to an unrelated class, but it does not support checking if there is a valid, polymorphic object at a particular memory location.

There is no smart way to check this, apart from maintaining a global list of valid pointers to `MyClass*` objects.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` would give you `NULL`, surely.

Comment: Not if you apply it to an arbitrary bit pattern, it just works with polymorphic objects.

Comment: I can vouch for that, Alexander. I had something similar (well, void*), and tested what throwing a garbage void* pointer at dynamic_cast does. It drops core is what it does.

Comment: I thought you couldn't use `dynamic_cast` at all? At least when I use it, I get an error saying "the operand of a pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class type".

Comment: Yes, first of all you would need a `reinterpret_cast` to get an appropriate pointer type for use with `dynamic_cast`. This shows already how wrong the whole thing is.

Answer (score 1):

there is almost no way to find out. you have to create some parent object for all of you objects (let's call it grand_dad) and then inherite all your objects from it. then use change LPARAM to `grand_dad*` and use `dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(lv.lparam)`.

a little notice about dynamic and static cast:

- static_cast is somthing that almost always do what you ask for, no checking at all!
- dynamic_cast on the other hand checks if the object is castable or not. if it isn't it returns NULL pointer. but it uses *virtual function table* to check your cast is legal so if the compiler doesn't know which function table to look (for example if it's casting from void*) it always return NULL pointer. if you pass some instance of A and call dynamic_cast to change it to isntance of B and they are not parent of each other you have to expect undifined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No need to crash. In Windows, use [structured exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can also make LONG magic_number the first field of MyClass and check it as extra insurance that it isn't some other object.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution is to keep a list ov valid `MyClass` objects. In every ctor, add `this` to the list; in the destructor you remove it from the list.

This doesn't protect you against coincidences, but even then you have a valid `MyClass*`. It even covers derived classes, since they do call base constructors.